# How can LastPass enforce 2-factor authentication

Tags: authentication, multi-factor

I've recently started using LastPass and one of the things you can set as a policy for you password vault is

> Prevent offline access when using Google Authenticator. The local
>   cache can be accessed without a second factor when using Google
>   Authenticator [unless this policy is enabled]

How can they enforce that? If they somehow encrypt my password db with a key returned by the google authentication procedure then how can they allow offline access in the first place? And if they don't encrypt it with something from google then how can they prevent offline access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can they enforce that?

The browser plugin will not store the data permanently on your local machine if `Permit Offline Access` is set to `Disallow`. It is only available while your internet connection is active and your session with LastPass is current.

> If they somehow encrypt my password db with a key returned by the google authentication procedure then how can they allow offline access in the first place? And if they don't encrypt it with something from google then how can they prevent offline access?

They don't encrypt the password DB with the 2 factor authentication key - only with your master password (or rather a key derived from it). The 2FA key only determines whether their server allows you access to the password DB and is not used in decryption.

There's [a little bit of further information here](https://lastpass.com/support.php?cmd=showfaq&id=2775).

Answer (score 0):

They probably wrote a 'server' module for it. GA uses shared secrets.  Their module would have the same secret as your GA client.

If so, the next question is: how are they securing the shared secret?  The GA pam module suffers the same issue.  Each linux server needs either the same shared secret (very bad) or you need a domain for each server (hard to scale). More on the GA pam module here: https://www.wikidsystems.com/WiKIDBlog/5-issues-enterprises-should-consider-before-using-google-authenticator-for-ssh.